# How to Pause / Resume Training in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

This question was made before the documentation for save and restore was available.
For now I would consider this question deprecated and say people to rely on the official documentation on [Save and Restore](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model)

Gist of old question:

> I got **TF** working fine for the [CIFAR Tutorial](http://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.md#launching_and_training_the_model).  I've changed
>   the code to save the `train_dir` (directory with checkpoint and
>   models) to a know location.
>
> Which brings me to my **question** :How can I pause and resume some
>   training with **TF** ?

Answer (score 14):

TensorFlow uses Graph-like computation, Nodes(Ops) and Edges(Variables aka states) and it provide a `Saver` for it's Vars.

So as it's distributed computation you can run part of a graph in one machine/processor and the rest in the other, meanwhile you can save the state(Vars) and feed it next time to continue your work.

```
saver.save(sess, 'my-model', global_step=0) ==> filename: 'my-model-0'
...
saver.save(sess, 'my-model', global_step=1000) ==> filename: 'my-model-1000'
```

which later you can use

```
tf.train.Saver.restore(sess, save_path)
```

to restore your saved Vars.

[Saver Usage](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#saving_and_restoring_variables)

Comment: Using this command tf.train.Saver.restore(sess, save_path) will cause an error because the restore method needs a Saver instance.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession() helped me to resume my training when my machine restarted.

#### Things to keep in Mind:

1. Make sure you are saving your checkpoints. In tf.train.saver() you can specify max_checkpoints to keep.
2. Specify the directory of the checkpoints in the tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(*checkpoint='dir_path',save_checkpoint_secs=*).
   Based on the *save_checkpoint_secs* argument, the above session would keep saving and updating the checkpoints.
3. When you constantly keep saving the checkpoints, above function, looks for the latest checkpoint and resumes training from there.

Answer (score 2):

As described by Hamed, the right way to do it on tensorflow is

```
    saver=tf.train.Saver()
    save_path='checkpoints/'
    -----> while training you can store using
    saver.save(sess=session,save_path=save_path)
    -----> and restore
    saver.restore(sess=session,save_path=save_path)
```

this will load the model where you last saved it and will the training(if you want) from there only.

Answer (score 1):

With Tensorflow 2 you can now use the [`BackupAndRestore` callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/BackupAndRestore) when invoking your model's `fit` function:

```py
model.fit(
  train_dataset,
  validation_data=validation_dataset,
  epochs=25,
  callbacks=[
    tf.keras.callbacks.BackupAndRestore(
      # The path where your backups will be saved. Make sure the
      # directory exists prior to invoking `fit`.
      "./training_backup",
      # How often you wish to save a checkpoint. Providing "epoch"
      # saves every epoch, providing integer n will save every n steps.
      save_freq="epoch",
      # Deletes the last checkpoint when saving a new one.
      delete_checkpoint=True,
    )
  ]
)
```

If your `fit` function exits for whatever reason, just invoke it again and the callback will take care of loading the most recent checkpoint and continuing your progress.

Answer (score 0):

1.Open checkpoint file and remove unwanted models from it.
2.Set `model_checkpoint_path` to last best model that you want to continue it.
content of file is such this:

```
model_checkpoint_path: "model_gs_043k"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "model_gs_041k"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "model_gs_042k"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "model_gs_043k"
```

Here, it continues from `model_gs_043k`

3.Remove the files also and then remove events files if exists then you can run your training.
The training will be started from last best saved model that exists in model folder. If no model file exists, training will be started from begin.