# Image classification with TensorFlow CNN

Tags: image-processing, classification, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm very new to Image Classification with CNNs and I followed the Tutorial for googles CNN: [https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#convolutional-neural-networks)

And this works very well but suddenly stops after training and evaluation of the model. I don't know why they stop :(

Does anybody know if there is a python function like:

```
loadModel("/path/to/my/trained/model");    
classify("/imagepath/image.png");
```

that return me the class and if possible all pixels of the object that was found. Or whats the way to do this?

Comment: this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33690809/3419997) will help you with the same.

Comment: mmm cant find any possible solution for my prob on your link. Can you pls be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to be more specific about "stop to work". What is the problem? Do you get the error or it freezes somewhere?
Secondly, [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html) maybe useful for you

Comment: no i mean the tutorial stoped. No more information about how to use the trained net

Answer (score 0):

```
#to save a model
sess = tf.Session()
saver.save(sess, '/path/to/my/saved/model/my_test_model)
```

## To load saved model in tensor flow

```
with tf.Session() as sess:    
    saver = 
    tf.train.import_meta_graph('/path/to/my/saved/model/my_test_model-
    1000.meta',clear_devices=True)
    saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

## predict on loaded model

```
sess.run(tf.argmax(y, 1), feed_dict={x: [img]})
```