# How can i stop model training and resume it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am working on object detection with autonomous datasets . I want to train my model with 10000 train images,2000 test,2000 validation images.I will use object detection tensorflow lite model maker.

Project link : tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_object_detection

After setting batch size 32, the training takes 50 epochs and continues for 2 days(Step 3).I can’t keep my computer on for two days.I am running the project in jupyter notebook

How can i stop model training and again resume it ? (e.g. stop the 10th epoch and continue one day later)

Answer (score 0):

I sure it depend on your code you working on. You can do that with tensorflow  check
[How to Pause / Resume Training in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689598/how-to-pause-resume-training-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score -1):

a sleep mode is a better option.
it will make your pc rest for some time and your work will be resumed after you log in again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).